# OWL punning to represent a placeholder or abstract class

Tags: owl, ontology

I'm trying to develop an ontology to represent a curricula, and in this curricula a student must take 6 elective courses (and has a long list of courses from which to choose).

Right now I have this classes:

```
- Course
--- Elective (defined class by isElective = true && type = Course)
```

And all my possible elective courses are instances of the type `Course` with the data property `isElective` set to true.

But I want to represent that this 6 elective courses must be taken in a certain way, for instance, a student needs to take 4 of this courses on the last year (`Year` is a class) of the curricula.

I have been thinking of how to define this placeholder/abstract class, which as I have read [isn't possible and doesn't make sense](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/protege-owl/2007-September/003823.html), and came across punning but I don't know if it is what I'm looking for.

Let's say I define a subclass of `Course` called `ElectivePlaceholder`, and then then 4 instances of this class where:

```
ElectiveX instanceOf ElectivePlaceholder
Year5 instanceOf Year
ElectiveX isPartOf Year5
```

Then I want to have a way to represent that a student choose to take `AdvancedMaths` (instance of `Elective`, aka instance of `Course` with `isElective` set to true) as it's `ElectiveX`.

How would I do that? Would punning be useful? Since it allows an object to treated as both a class and an individual.

**Update**

What I'm trying to model is not what a student chooses but the curricula itself.

Each curricula individual has different requirements as to how many elective courses the students must undertake and in which years. I need to represent this in a way either on the `Curricula` individual or the `Year` individual (so it can be inferred for the `Curricula`).

Right now:

```
YearX partOf CurriculaX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Punning](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F12:_Punning) will not solve your problem. Punning allows you to refer to say `Course` as both an OWL class and an OWL individual.

You can achieve your desired result by defining your ontology as follows:

```
ObjectProperty: hasCourse
    Domain: Curricula
    Range: Course

Class: Curricula
    SubClassOf: 
        taughtInYear some xsd:integer,
        hasCourse some Course 

Class: CurriculaDifficult
    SubClassOf: 
        Curricula,
        hasCourse min 4 ElectiveCourse,
        hasCourse max 9 Course

Class: CurriculaEasy
    SubClassOf: 
        Curricula,
        hasCourse min 1 ElectiveCourse,
        hasCourse max 3 Course

Class: ElectiveCourse
    SubClassOf: Course    
    DisjointWith: NonElectiveCourse

Class: NonElectiveCourse
    SubClassOf: Course    
    DisjointWith: ElectiveCourse

Class: Course

Individual: AdvancedMaths
    Types: ElectiveCourse

Individual: curriculaEasy2018
   Types: CurriculaEasy

   Facts:
     taughtInYear 2018,
     hasCourse someCourseA,
     hasCourse someCourseB,
     hasCourse someElectiveCourseA        

Class Student:
  SubClassOf: takeCurricula some Curricula

Individual: student123
   Types: Student
   Facts:
      takeCurricula curriculaEasy2018
```

A couple of things to note are:

(1) Abstract classes (that are well regarded programming concepts) cannot be represented in OWL. I explain some surprising things that OWL lacks coming from a programming background [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/04/15/object-oriented-features-that-owl-lacks/).

(2) Rather than having `isElective` as a property that you associate with a `Course` it is better to model it as `ElectiveCourse` versus `NonElectiveCourse` that are disjoint. Reason being that if you ever want to extend the definition of `NonElectiveCourse` you can do that. This is also in coding the reason why it is best to avoid flags.

(3) You have to **close** your `Curricula` in some way by stating what the maximum number of courses are otherwise, due to the **open world assumption**, the reasoner will have no way to know that you have **not** specified at least 4 `ElectiveCourse`s. I have written about this [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/03/09/why-does-the-reasoner-ignore-my-constraint/).

** UPDATE ** 
So you can add `CurruculaEasy` and `CurruculaDifficult` classes with different numbers of requirements for electives as shown above. You can add a `Curricula` that is the super class of `CurruculaEasy` and `CurriculaDifficult`. For `Curricula` you add that it subclasses `taughtInYear some xsd:integer` as shown above.

Comment: Can I set the min and max hasCourse for each individual of type `Curricula` or `Year`? I left a small update on the question based on your explanations, and thanks for all the extra info

Comment: Yes, you can. This models the curricula, not what the student has chosen.

Comment: Updated answer.